# Browser detection in ASP.Net 4

Tags: asp.net

I have requirement to check browser detection in ASP.Net 4.0.

In this I need to check all browser including latest smart phone browsers also.

currently I am using code mention in this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3yekbd5b

Is there any other better approach for this.

Comment: Check the [user agent string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx). It's not 100% realiabe either, but it's better than what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I have found MS browser detection to be clunky and has a dependency on local .browser files. With additional maintenance updating I find this method out-dated. SAAS parties such as:

51 degrees mobile detection
http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Provide a more consistent and reliable system.